# Начал изучать CodeIgniter - есть пару вопросов

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty

В общем раньше занимался разработкой проектов на своей CMS, построенной без классов (только в некоторых случая как библиотеки). Решил попробовать CI. Поставил CI, подключил smarty.

Возникли вопросы:

1) есть форма авторизации, понятное дело, что если ты авторизован, то выводить ее не нужно. 
Где делать такую проверку, неужели в каждом методе контроллера?

2) для тех, кто использует CI + smarty: нужно в каждом методе делать "$this->tpl->display" шаблона, нельзя ли в каком-то одном месте определить этот шаблон, а внутренние страницы подключать через переменную, например, так:

```
$this->tpl->assign("main", "main.tpl.html") ;
$this->tpl->display("index.tpl.html") ;
```

Сейчас приходится в каждом методе проделывать такие операции.

Comment: > есть форма авторизации, понятное дело, что если ты авторизован, то выводить ее не нужно. Где делать такую проверку, неужели в каждом методе контроллера?

C CI не знаком, но, конечно, нет. В Yii бы в основном лейауте выводился виджет, который проверял бы авторизацию, и, если пользователь авторизован, не выводил бы ничего.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я делал базовый класс-контроллер, в конструкторе которого проходил все проверки на авторизацию и прочее. Остальные классы контроллеры наследовал от него. Все просто, базовый класс обработав сессию в конструкторе, передавал управление классу потомку, тот уже не заботился о безопасности.

Comment: спасибо, понял суть, сделал базовый класс, в конструкторе объявил переменные шаблона для smarty, в другом конструкторе - потомке уже изменить эту переменную не получается. Может как-то по другом это делается?

Comment: Переменные класса не забудь выставить как протекдет, иначе в потомке, они будут не доступны.